# Toolbar property in XPages seems not to work after an partial refresh

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-notes

I got a problem with the toolbar property in the rich text field. On the first load everything looks as expected, but after a partial refresh you can see all buttons in the richtext editor.
It seems that you don't get the problem when you use slim, medium, large instead.

I use a Domino Server Version 9.0.1 FP3

Here is an example:

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="inputRichText1">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1">
    <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbar">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[[['Format']]]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: why do you want to refresh it?

Comment: one reason is, i change the value in ssjs and than i have to refresh it so that you can see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the toolbarType property instead, with values "Slim", "Medium" or "Large" ...

```
            <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1"
                    style="height:200.0px">
                <xp:this.dojoAttributes>
                    <xp:dojoAttribute name="toolBarType"
                        value="Slim">
                    </xp:dojoAttribute>
                </xp:this.dojoAttributes>
            </xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: change toolbar to toolbartype has the same effect. I know that slim, medium and large are working, but i need it more customised